# Lua with hard-float on MIPS by buildroot doesn't work

Tags: lua, mips, buildroot

I found something strange.

I wrote simple script that print the variable in Lua 5.1. It worked on x86 on linux. I tried to run it on my target device that is MIPS little endian. I prepared the lua by [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). I used 'hard-float' option for performance issue. But this simple script doesn't work. I used Sourcery CodeBench.

I tested it with 'soft-float' option. Then lua worked correctly. Have you the experience like that?

The code is like below.

```
local var = 131523;
print(var);
```

It must print `131523`. But my target printed `0`  . What's wrong?

Comment: This is the weirdest thing. I compiled Lua 5.2.3 with a completely different environment (clang/LLVM based ELLCC) and got similar results. ARM, i386, PowerPC, and x86_64 worked, mipshf failed, mipsf worked. Strange.

Comment: Interesting report. Could you make it a proper bug report at https://bugs.busybox.net/, in the "Buildroot" product, so that we can investigate that?

Comment: Have you confirmed that hard-float is enabled and working properly on your target?

Comment: OK, I'll report it into busybox's bug tracker . Its URL is https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=7844.  @markgz, I compiled other libraries and source code with hard-float option and it doesn't make any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that target CPU we used doesn't support floating point calculation.

Comment: Could You please clarify, which CPU was that?